# Is ggmap/sf still plotting point in wrong place?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, ggmap

Is this old bug **still** unresolved, or is there a reasonable workaround yet?

Some cities:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggmap)
require(sf)

cities = sf::read_sf('{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "cities",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "city": "London"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.13, 51.51]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "city": "Rome"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [12.48, 41.89]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "city": "Stockholm"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [18.07, 59.33]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "city": "Istanbul"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [28.96, 41.01]
      }
    }
  ]
}
')
```

And a ggmap basemap:

```
bb = c(left = -11, bottom = 35, right = 42, top = 65)
europe = ggmap::get_stamenmap(bbox = bb, maptype = 'toner-lite', zoom = 3)

ggmap(europe) + 
  geom_sf(data = cities, inherit.aes = FALSE, col = 'red', size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: your geom sf is based on a variant of `EPSG:4326`.  Your ggmap uses `3857`.  Overplotting them shouldn't line up perfectly.    Try addin `crs = 3857` to your `geom_sf()` call - not guaranteed to work but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @PaulStaffordAllen but that has no effect, as does using `st_transform(cities, to = st_crs(3857))` in `geom_sf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `ggmap` uses the co-ordinate object `CoordMap` to decide where to place pixels of a raster. By switching to `coord_sf` (which happens when you add a `geom_sf` layer), you are knocking the raster out of alignment. If you extract the co-ordinates of your points you can simply overlay them as a `geom_point` layer:

```r
ggmap(europe) + 
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(st_coordinates(cities)), aes(X, Y), 
             inherit.aes = FALSE, col = 'red', size = 3)
```

[image]

If you want to be able to draw more complex `sf` objects, then I would stay away from `ggmap` and use `maptiles`:

```r
library(maptiles)
library(tidyterra)

bb <- c(left = -11, bottom = 35, right = 42, top = 65)

europe <- matrix(bb, 2, byrow = TRUE) |>
  st_multipoint()       |> 
  st_sfc(crs = 4326)    |>
  st_transform(3857) |>
  get_tiles(provider = "Stadia.Stamen.TonerLite", zoom = 4, crop = TRUE)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = europe) +
  geom_sf(data = cities, size = 3, color = "red") +
  coord_sf(crs = 3857, expand = FALSE, ylim = st_bbox(europe)[c(2, 4)])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan. Yes this is simple enough for points but I recall it can get tricky for multi-polygons and multi-polylines. It would be much easier if we could reproject `cities` to crs 3857.

Comment: @geotheory as far as I can tell, there _is_ no projection as such. The stamen map is essentially a raster annotation on a planar co-ordinate system. It might be possible to convert `europe` to a `geom_tile` layer though.

Comment: @geotheory see my update for a workaround. It might be worth noting that Stamen are ceasing to host their maps in the near future, so it's not clear if stamen maps will be available in R for much longer without an API key.

Comment: Thanks Allan this works. Loss of Stamen is a real shame.